# Constructing conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking for a conformal mapping from the set $\mathbb{C} - [0,\infty)$ onto $\mid z \mid >1 $.

I have tried composing the Koebe function with rotations and translations but i can't seem to get the right thing!

Thanks!

Comment: Start with a $z\mapsto \sqrt{-z}$ to flatten out the boundary ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hint!

I used $z \rightarrow z^{1/2}$ to map $\mathbb{C}-[0,\infty)$ onto $Im(z)>0$.

Then the well known $ \frac{i-z}{i+z} $ to map $Im(z)>0$ onto $\mid z \mid <1$

And finally, $1/z$ to map $\mid z \mid <1$ onto $\mid z \mid >1 $.

Overall the map is given by $z \rightarrow  \frac{i+z^{1/2}}{i-z^{1/2}}$